# ASP.NET Core: webassembly controller not returning list within object to client

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, blazor-webassembly

I'm hoping someone has had this issue before and can help me out.  I have an ASP.NET Core 7 web assembly controller that returns a `User` object back to the client. The `User` object has a list of `Roles` associated with it.

When I issue an HTTP `GET` from the client to the server, everything seems to be working okay. However, when the object is returned back to the client, the embedded list of `Roles` isn't included.

Here is my client code:

```cs
    public async Task<Lightwave.Data.User> GetUserByUserId(string expand = default(string), int userId = default(int))
    {
        var uri = new Uri(_baseUri, $"Users({userId})");

        var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri);

        var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);

        var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); // No Roles List
                
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data.User>(json);
    }
```

Client JSON response (no roles list):

```json
    {
        "UserId": 2,
        "UserName": "Administrator",
        "FirstName": "Test",
        "LastName": "User",
        "EmailAddress": "testuser@test.com",
        "Active": true,
        "LastLogin": "2023-04-17T10:26:01.253Z",
        "LastModifiedUser": null,
        "LastModifiedDate": "2023-04-14T10:53:33.067Z"
    }
```

Controller code:

```cs
    [HttpGet("/odata/Lightwave/Users(UserId={UserId})")]
    public User GetUser(int key)
    {
        var user = _context.Users
                           .Include(i => i.Roles)
                           .Where(i => i.UserId == key)
                           .SingleOrDefault();

        // for debug purposes
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user);
        // end debug
    
        return user;
    }
```

Controller JSON (note: roles are included):

```json
    {
        "UserId": 2,
        "UserName": "Administrator",
        "FirstName": "Test",
        "LastName": "User",
        "EmailAddress": "testuser@test.com",
        "Active": true,
        "LastLogin": "2023-04-17T10:26:01.253",
        "LastModifiedUser": null,
        "LastModifiedDate": "2023-04-14T10:53:33.067",
        "Roles": [
            {
                "RoleId": 1,
                "RoleName": "Administrator",
                "Users": []
            }
        ]
    }
```

User/Role objects:

```cs
    public partial class User
    {
        public User()
        {
            Roles = new List<Role>();
            UserQueries = new List<UserQuery>();
        }

        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
    
        [Required]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string? FirstName { get; set; }
        public string? LastName { get; set; }
        public string? EmailAddress { get; set; }
    
        public bool Active { get; set; } = true; 
        public DateTime? LastLogin { get; set; }

        public string? LastModifiedUser { get; set; }
        public DateTime? LastModifiedDate { get; set; }
    
        public ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    }
    [Table("Role", Schema = "dbo")]
        public partial class Role
        {
            public Role() 
            { 
                Users = new List<User>();
            }
            [Key]
            [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
            public int RoleId { get; set; }
    
            [Required]
            public string RoleName { get; set; }
    
            //public ICollection<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
            public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
    
        }
```

Comment: is the user model property names identical in the server and client? and they are different please include a code snippet of the remaining user model

Comment: Yes.  They are identical and marked as public.  The client and server share the same class.

Comment: What are getting within `json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user);`? I cannot see any mappings with user and roles. How they are related could you please share?

Comment: User and Role have a many-to-many relationship with one another.

Comment: I would rxpect JSon to have problems with "many to many". But as long as Role.Users remains empty it could work.  Do you apply any Json settings for recursion?  If so, post them.

Comment: But as a general rule and probably the solution: use dedicated DTO classes for the communication.

Comment: I don't apply any settings for recursion.  Do you recommend any to try?